# Checking the log4j properties of a running Java process

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am wondering if there is a way to check log4j properties of running Java process. I am facing an issue regarding this. I set the configuration to INFO level and am using Rolling file appender. The system starts up and work fine for a minute and logs go the appropriate file. But suddenly it starts logging to Console at DEBUG level and it no longer goes to the File. Most probably some modules reset the Log4j properties to some other values. I tried putting breaks on few methods on Log4j property Configurator. But it didn't help much as may be I didn't put breaks on appropriate method. 
Any clue is greatly appreciated.

I configured log4j with below configuration, but that configuration seems no longer in after few seconds

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1,A2

log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File = ${storm.home}/logs/${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.A1.Append = true
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.A2=com.proptotype.poc.CustomAppender
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
log4j.appender.A2.myName=scribe
log4j.appender.A2.scribeHost=127.0.0.1
log4j.appender.A2.scribePort=1464
```

Comment: please show your log4j.properties

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Log4j 2, you can use JMX to query and modify your current loggers configuration.

It even have a small Gui application to do that :  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html#ClientGUI

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find out what is the current log level you can do it as follows.

```
System.out.println(Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel());
```

Similarly you can find out other properties also from the Logger class for eg:

```
Enumeration enums = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
        while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(enums.nextElement().toString());
        }
```